# Hover with jquery and div encapsulation

Tags: jquery

I have a div in a div, with a padding.

Like this : http://jsfiddle.net/qevoxh5f/3/

That is very very strange because this jsfiddle is a minimalist copy of my project, and I have different result ...

In my project, when my mouse is on the calendar div, the hover is working, but when i decide to move to the clndr div (inside de calendar div) jQuery decide to remove class, and reset it immediatly, which gives a small flashing effect ...

And strangely, this is working correctly on jsfiddle (on chrome and firefox )... 
And even worse : the hover blink effect is only visible on my project on google chrome.

http://media.giphy.com/media/26BkMl08chKm9kq5O/giphy.gif gif of my problem

Any ideas ?

```
$('#calendar').mouseover(function () {
  $(this).addClass('hover-month')
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-month')
});

$('.week').mouseover(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(this).addClass('hover-week')
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-week')
});
```

Comment: Add a "boolean" variable on mouseover and restrict the events that happen: <br/>
`$('#calendar').mouseover(function () {
  if(!childMouseovered) {
       $(this).addClass('hover-month');
  }
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-month')
});`

<br/>
`$('.week').mouseover(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(this).addClass('hover-week');
  childMouseovered = true;
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).removeClass('hover-week')
  childMouseovered = false;
});`

Comment: simply `$('#calendar').hover(function () {  $(this).toggleClass('hover-month') });` and  `$('.week').hover(function () {  $(this).toggleClass('hover-week') });`

Comment: Ty Jquery King, but with this code, when i start with my mouse inside a div in calendar, the hover effect is reversed :) And i don't want the calendar div to stay hover when i select a div inside, that's why i used stopPropagation

Comment: @victor175 i have the same problem with this code (look at my gif) http://media.giphy.com/media/26BkMl08chKm9kq5O/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#calendar').hover(function () { 
  $(this).toggleClass('hover-month') ;
}); 

$('.week').hover(function () { 
  $(this).toggleClass('hover-week'); 
  $('#calendar').toggleClass('hover-month');
});
```

Comment: this is answer to your question? or you try to edit your question?

Comment: Actually this is the answer of my question, but i can't accept it today